# Add Jira Link to Confluence Page Programmatically

Tags: powershell, jira, confluence

I've managed to create a confluence page with powershell programmatically. Now I want to add a link to a jira ticket inside the page.

```
$Headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Basic xxxxxxxx";
    "Origin" = "https://mydomain.atlassian.net"
}

$Uri = "https://mydomain.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content"

$Body = @{
    "type" = "page"
    "title" = "Test Page"
    "space" = @{
         "key" = "MYSPACE"
    }
    "ancestors" = @(
        @{
         "id" = 1234567
        }
    )
    "body" = @{
         "storage" = @{
              "value" = '<ri:shortcut ri:key="jira" ri:parameter="ISSUE-1234"/>'
              "representation" = "storage"
         }
    }
}

$Body = $Body | ConvertTo-Json 

Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Headers -Method POST -Uri $Uri -ContentType "application/json; charset=UTF-8" -Body ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Body))
```

The storage format is documented [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/confluence-storage-format-790796544.html) but unfortunatly the issue is not displayed on the page. It does not recognize the <ri:shortcut> element...

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to add a link to the jira ticket via Wiki Markup

```
"storage" = @{
   "value" = '{jira:ISSUE-1234}'
   "representation" = "wiki"
}
```

Comment: Nice and interesting solution indeed. I usually save whatever I need on a page then investigate page storage format how is it actually saved. Format of Jira links is quite complex, but wiki representation you used is way shorter. However, you might get into troubles when you will need to update existing (and possibly long) pages and include an extra Jira link. You will get the storage format in XML and you won't be probably able to add Jira link using the wiki representation.